# Error in Visual Basic and I have no idea why

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

First of all i'm french so excuse me if i make some mistakes

I begin in Visual Basic, i have been in class since 2 months and i have my first "big" project at the university

My module is the following:

```
Public Function CanPlay(ByVal i As Integer) As Boolean

Dim possible As Boolean
Dim t() As Integer

For i = 1 to 6
If t(i) = 0 Then
possible = False
Else possible = True

Next i
Return possible

End Function
```

I am creating a game named Kalaha and need to say if a player can play or not, if t(i) is equal to 0 on all his cases, player can't play
But my first " t(i) = 0" doesn't work, he underlined it in green and say there is no value assigned for t but i just declared it at the beginning ...

Comment: You have declared a variable for an array of integers. But you haven't set its dimension (how many elements to store) then you try to loop over that variable 6 times. This fails. If you have doubts I suggest to read some introductory materials on VB.NET and programming in general

Comment: you should break the for loop when the condition is true of false, you always return the condition of t(6)

Comment: Steve is right, you need to dimension your array.  Also, unless your For loop starts at i=0 you are going to miss the first value in your array since arrays are 0 based.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks ! Error has disappeared ... Now I hope that my module  work when I will link it with the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attempt to declare the array of "t" is incorrect and no attempt was made to initialize it with values.

The following line can be used to both declare and initialize the array.

```
Dim t As Integer() = New Integer() {0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
```

Also note that VB.NET uses zero based arrays, so your first array value is t(0).

Comment: Yes thanks, i changed it to 0 and all of my others t() and variable

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pass i to the CanPlay function as a parameter. i can be declared in the loop. It is more likely that you will be passing the t array as a parameter rather than declaring it locally.

As JohnH pointed out, VB.NET arrays begin at element zero. You can iterate to t.GetUpperBound(0) to capture every element up to the highest element of the array. If you go over the highest element, you will get an "out of bounds" exception.

You don't need the "possible" boolean variable. As mcNets pointed out, you are going to return t(6) every time you call CanPlay which makes the loop pointless. Simply return True as soon as you find a non-zero value in the array. If you exit the loop without returning True, it means that a zero value was not found and therefore the return value is False.

```
Public Function CanPlay(ByVal t As Integer()) As Boolean
    For i As Integer = 0 to t.GetUpperBound(0)
        If t(i) <> 0 Then Return True
    Next

    Return False
End Function
```

You would call the CanPlay function as follows:

```
Dim bCanPlay As Boolean = CanPlay(New Integer() {0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 })
```